# Alternative definition of continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity

How to prove that:
if $f$ is not continuous at $x$ , there exists a neighbourhood $B$ of $f(x)$ in $Y$ such that for all neghbourhoods $A$ of $x$ in $X$ , we have that  $f(A)$  is not a subset of $B$. Not  just $f(A) \neq B$

**My Attempt:** $f$ is continuous at the point $x_0$ iff the preimage of every open set containing $f(x_0)$ will be open set in $X$. I know this definition. I can not understand how the given statement is derived. Can anyone please give me a hint ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124966/discussion-on-question-by-sani-alternative-definition-of-continuity).

Comment: Your definition of "continuous at the point $x_0$" is incorrect.